# How to Access installed apps between two sf org using sso

Tags: single-sign-on

Is there a way we can access an app exchange tool installed in other sf org from another sf org, using single sign on?
For example, if I login to one sf org, clicking a button should open an app that is installed in another sf org. We are implementing an enterprise tool and would like multiple sf orgs to access the tool which is installed in a different sf org. I know using canvas we can call any third party app from Salesforce. But can we also call the installed app exchange app? We do not want users to swivel chair between the orgs. It should be a seamless user experience. Any suggestion would be grately appreciated.

Best,
PSH

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call an app in another org without a valid session for that org. There's at least a few ways I can think of that you could do this. Keep in mind that this means you'll have to configure profiles in the other org, and additional licenses may be required.

## Install the App

Just install the app in each org. Depending on the provider of the app, they may choose to not double-charge you for the license use, but you're at their mercy. If it's a free app, though, that should be a trivial matter. This is probably the least costly solution in any event, unless the cost of the licensing exceeds the cost of your Salesforce licenses.

## Single Sign On

You can grant access between orgs using the Single Sign On. Essentially, each org would be an Identity Provider for the other org. This would allow users to hop between orgs effortlessly. Both orgs would need to have My Domain configured, as well as the appropriate certificates, etc installed in each org. Users will need one Salesforce license per org, though.

## Force.com Site

You can configure a Site for the org that has the app. Depending on the specific features, however, this may or may not be practical (may require additional licenses beyond normal user licenses). Portal licenses are less expensive, but depending on the features you need, it may not suit your purposes.

---

I suggest doing some additional research, including contacting the app provider and your salesforce.com Account Executive or Customer Success Manager to determine which route will be the most cost effective.